# Factoring polynomials; pre-calculus

Tags: polynomials, factoring

$(x-y)^{2}+2(y-x)-24$

Answer: $(x-y-6)(x-y+4)$

I couldn't find a way to get to this answer, may you give me a hint in the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$y-x = -(x-y)$$${}{}{}{}{}$

After which you can factor in the same way considering $x-y$

Comment: Got it!! Now I can do the sum and product of the -2 and -24!!

Comment: -6+4=-2 and -6×4=-24

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

take $T=x-y$ so we have $T^2-2T-24$. then you can factor it as $(T-6)(T+4)$

Comment: Got it!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  complete the square $\;(x-y)^{2}-2(x-y)\color{red}{+1-1}-24= (x-y-1)^2 - 5^2\,$.